# After send subview to back in uitableview, how to touch the subview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, hittest

I use a `headerview` as a `UITableView` subview, now I want to dynamic hide some view in the `headerview`. My solution is send the `headerview` to back of the `UITableView` and update the *contentoffset* of the `UITableView`.

Like this:(before)
The red rectangle is the `headerview` and the green one is the `hiddenview`.

[image]

(after)

[image]

But I can not touch button, textfield etc now. I have tried the `hittest` and `pointinside` methods, but it did not work. Maybe I use the wrong way. So anybody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not using setHidden property?

Comment: @BharatModi Because the hidden view in the headerview, the headerview still there, cover the first cell.

Comment: Can you mark the header view in your image? Its hard to find the header View in the above image.

Comment: @BharatModi Sure, sorry about that.

Comment: If you are using auto layouts, try adding height constraint to the view you want to hide. make outlet of the same and set its constant to 0 when you want to hide that view.

Comment: @BharatModi maybe I should take another way, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide subviews using headerview.subview.hidden = YES and updateConstraints if you are using auto layout otherwise update frame.

Comment: thanks, yes, maybe I should take another way, but I still want to know how to touch the subview properly.

Comment: if you send it back you can't, thats the purpose of sending view back :D